# To Implement a DVD player functionality for Android Auto , Should I extend the TV HAL?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-tv, android-hardware, android-auto

I need to add DVD Player support for Android Auto, I was wondering where would the DVD Player support code go , as I cannot find a HAL or supporting code for this. I was thinking about extending the TV HAL tv_input.h , which could break the compatibility.

What is the most efficient solution for this architecturally?. If i can configure the DVD output via pass-through TV?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use: https://source.android.com/compatibility/8.1/android-8.1-cdd#9_14_automotive_vehicle_system_isolation (and the link to the Automotive HAL within)

Comment: @Morrison Chang I did look in the automotive hal, there's  Evs with camera and IVI HALs only supports Bluetooth, message and Audio and I can't find DVD or cd player support in any of the HALs , which seems strange to me. Do you know any such implementation where there could be such support probably in IVI?

Comment: Per the documentation Android Auto only supports Messaging and Audio apps: https://developer.android.com/training/auto/start/ Perhaps if you describe what you expect Android Auto to provide from any supporting device/phone running an app which needs to pass Google's quality guidelines: https://developer.android.com/docs/quality-guidelines/auto-app-quality